# Deleting items in a dictionary of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, dictionary

This is my sample input file:

```
{
"name": "756",
"children": [{
    "name": "Process Activities",
    "children": [{
        "name": "LOAD LIBRARY::shell32.dll"
    }, {
        "name": "#REDCREATE PROCESS::DLL INJECTION INTO PROCESS WITH ID 680 App=[C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp /SL5=$1D0314,1364673,56832,C://Blues//file.s62451 ]"
    }, {
        "name": "#REDLOAD LIBRARY::comctl32.dll"
    }, {
        "name": "LOAD LIBRARY::C://Windows//system32//uxtheme.dll"
    }, {
        "name": "LOAD LIBRARY::dwmapi.dll"
    }, {
        "name": "LOAD LIBRARY::UxTheme.dll"
    }, {
        "name": "#REDPROCESS CREATE::C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp /SL5=$1D0314,1364673,56832,C://Blues//file.s62451"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "File Activities",
    "children": [{
        "name": "FILE READ::C://Blues//file.s62451"
    }, {
        "name": "FILE OPEN::<R>C://Blues//file.s62451"
    }, {
        "name": "FILE OPEN::<W>C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp"
    }, {
        "name": "#REDEXECUTABLE FILE WRITE::C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp"
    }, {
        "name": "FILE CLOSE::C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp"
    }, {
        "name": "FILE CLOSE::C://Blues//file.s62451"
    }, {
        "name": "FILE OPEN::<R>C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "680",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Process Activities",
        "children": [{
            "name": "#REDCURRENT PROCESS::C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp"
        }, {
            "name": "LOAD LIBRARY::C://Windows//system32//uxtheme.dll"
        }, {
            "name": "LOAD LIBRARY::dwmapi.dll"
        }, {
            "name": "LOAD LIBRARY::ADVAPI32.dll"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "File Activities",
        "children": [{
            "name": "FILE OPEN::<R>C://Windows//Fonts//staticcache.dat"
        }, {
            "name": "FILE READ::C://Windows//Fonts//staticcache.dat"
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

If I have a child with the name Process Activities, File Activities, Registry Activities or Network Activities, I have to delete that child other wise not. So the process goes on like a tree.

This is the output for above sample:

```
{
"name": "756",
"children": [{
    "name": "680",
    "children": []
}
```

I tried the following:
Here is my code:

```
import json
def infosorting(sample_dict):
   if sample_dict["name"] not in ['Process Activities', 'File Activities', 'Registry Activities', 'Network Activities']:
    for child in sample_dict["children"]:
          if child["name"] in ['Process Activities', 'File Activities', 'Registry Activities', 'Network Activities']:

       #sample_dict["children"].pop(sample_dict["children"].index(child))
                sample_dict["children"].remove(child)
                #del child

          else:
                infosorting(child)
  else:
    sample_dict ={}
  return sample_dict
def main():
  file_sample = open("/home/manchala/PdfJson/md5/file11.txt")
  fs = file_sample.read()
  sample_dict = json.loads(fs)
  new_dict=infosorting(sample_dict)
  print new_dict
if __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```

but i am getting output like this

```
{
u 'name': u '756', u 'children': [{
    u 'name': u 'File Activities',
    u 'children': [{
        u 'name': u 'FILE READ::C://Blues//file.s62451'
    }, {
        u 'name': u 'FILE OPEN::<R>C://Blues//file.s62451'
    }, {
        u 'name': u 'FILE OPEN::<W>C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp'
    }, {
        u 'name': u '#REDEXECUTABLE FILE WRITE::C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp'
    }, {
        u 'name': u 'FILE CLOSE::C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp'
    }, {
        u 'name': u 'FILE CLOSE::C://Blues//file.s62451'
    }, {
        u 'name': u 'FILE OPEN::<R>C://Users//blues//AppData//Local//Temp//is-Q43LA.tmp//file.tmp'
    }]
}, {
    u 'name': u '680',
    u 'children': [{
        u 'name': u 'File Activities',
        u 'children': [{
            u 'name': u 'FILE OPEN::<R>C://Windows//Fonts//staticcache.dat'
        }, {
            u 'name': u 'FILE READ::C://Windows//Fonts//staticcache.dat'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

Why am I not able to delete the child with name 'File Activities'?
Please help me figure out what was wrong in my code and help me correct it.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to modify an object while iterating over it - you are better off creating a new object as you iterate (so build a `children` list of items that don't match, and then replace `sample_dict['children']` with this list.